# Sprites are drawing at the wrong, but right location

Tags: java, android, libgdx

```
public void render() {
if (TimeUtils.nanoTime() - lastSpawn > 2100000000)
            chooseLane();
}

private void spawnCar() {

        Rectangle car2 = new Rectangle();

    float Pos123 = MathUtils.random(0, 2);
    if (Pos123 == 0) {
        car2.x = 60;

    }
    if (Pos123 == 1) {
        car2.x = 180;

    }
    if (Pos123 == 2) {
        car2.x = 300;
    }

    car = new Rectangle();
    car.width = 100;
    car.height = 172;

    car2.y = 1000;
    car2.setWidth(100);
    car2.setHeight(172);
    carb.add(car2);
    lastSpawn = TimeUtils.nanoTime();

}
```

The sprites are drawing at one of these three locations every time but when I do a `System.out.println(Pos123)` the Sprite doesn't correlate to the actually lane that it has spawned in. This is also throwing the collision detector out of whack because it's triggering in the wrong lanes

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? After you call `System.out.println(Pos123)` in `spawnCar` method you'll get either 0, 1 or 2 as a result. What output do you receive?

Comment: Yeah just checking what is randomed and assigned to Pos123, seems like it doesnt matter what number is randomed according to the position of the Sprites